# Tags for Isabelle Locales and Classes

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I believe having a [locales](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locales) for Isabelle will help with organizing questions. I have added Tag info but it is still pending in peer review.

Now the main question is about [this question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/249/are-subclass-and-instance-commands-equivalent-in-defining-subclass-relation) which is currently only tagged with [isabelle](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isabelle). I see three options (Isar type classes are basically locales):

1. create a new [classes](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classes)
2. create a new [classes](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classes) as a synonym for [locales](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locales)
3. use the existing [locales](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locales)

---

Personally, I tend to favour option (2) which makes explicit that it is a different concept but still highlights the link between the two.

Comment: I like your proposal and would favour option (2) as well